# Sed over a long list using cat

Tags: linux, sed, cat

I am trying to change some lines of a code using sed by reading another list of 7000+ lines using cat.

I tried to do :

```
for i in `cat namefile`; do sed 's/OG0000047/$i/g' paml.ctr > paml_$i.ctr; done
```

My code (paml.ctr):

```
seqfile = OG0000047.phy  
treefile = OG0000047.treefile     
outfile = OG0000047_results
```

My list (namefile):

```
OG0000047
OG0000076
OG0000080
OG0000194
OG0000223
OG0000255
OG0000271
```

So read the names on the namefile and change OG0000047 to the names, save into a new file. However, of course, my $I in the sed command does not work and I end up with $I in my code instead of the actual names

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: 1. Don't use `` `whatever` ``, but `$(whatever)`. 2. To provide [repro] you should add the example input and output.

Comment: Use double quotes to expand `$i` in sed

Comment: That makes sense now that I think of it, but I don't know how else I should do

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work.

```
for i in `cat namefile`; do sed -e "s/OG0000047/$i/g" paml.ctr > maol_$i.ctr;  done
```

Comment: It does work, thank you so much. So I was missing the -e and s

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and xargs):

```
cat namefile |xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c "sed 's/OG0000047/{}/g' paml.ctr > paml_{}.ctr"
```

Use the `namefile` as arguments for both `sed` and the new file name.

The `-I{}` means use `{}` as a stub for the argument and `-n1` means issue the the `sh` command (sed with redirection) one at a time.

Alternative, using GNU parallel:

```
parallel "sed 's/OG0000047/{}/g' paml.ctr > paml_{}.ctr" :::: namefile
```